# R Shiny theme colors do not like call to an html page

Tags: html, r, colors, themes, shiny

I have a Shiny app using R code which attempts to use a bootstrap theme **bootstrap_united.css**:

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
#
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        theme = "bootstrap_united.css",
        navbarPage("",
            tabPanel("Input and display your text",                            
                fluidRow(
                    column(width = 6, 
                        wellPanel(
                            h5("Your input ="),
                            tags$style(type="text/css", "textarea {width:100%}"),
                            tags$textarea(id = "myText", rows = 22, "")
                        )
                    ),
                    column(width = 6,
                        wellPanel(
                            h5("Our output ="),
                            verbatimTextOutput("myText")
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            tabPanel("Help page",
                fluidRow(
                    includeHTML("help.html")
                    # h5("This works!")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and

```
# server.R
library(shiny)
#
shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
        output$myText <- renderText({input$myText})
    }
)
```

The second tabPanel attempts to call an html file which is saved in the same folder as the **ui.R** and **server.R** files. The call is successful, and the page is displayed, but the presence of this page causes the theme colors from the CSS file to not be shown, and so everything in the R Shiny app is displayed in monochrome shades of gray.

However, if the second tabPanel just displays some text {e.g. shown as **# h5("Our output =")** in the R code} instead of an html page, then the theme is used/displayed correctly, and the app is displayed in color.

How can I adapt the R code in the shiny app so that the html page will be displayed, **and** the theme will be displayed correctly too?

Comment: There a number of things that could go wrong here, could you provide all the files you are using: `help.html` and `bootstrap_united.css`?

Comment: You can upload them on fileshare or github and post link here

Comment: Hi @PorkChop , I'll upload them later today on github. Will let you know once they are up. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @PorkChop , apologies for the delay. I had trouble uploading files to GitHub. They can be found here under "1st commit": https://github.com/ICF2001D/R1_20151121     Thanks!